# Syntax highlighter for HTML and PHP

Tags: javascript, regex, formatting, grammar

I've created a JavaScript application to highlight the syntax of HTML and PHP. I know a lot of syntax highlighter are available nowadays, I just created to extend my knowledge in JS and regular expressions. I only wanted to know if its the right way to do this. (The code below works fine.)

**js/codeHighlighter.js**

```
function codeHighlighter(){
    var obj=document.getElementsByTagName("code");
    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
        var data=obj[i].innerHTML;
        data=data.replace(/&lt;(.*?)&gt;/g,"<span class='html-tag'>&lt;$1&gt;</span>");
        data=data.replace(/"(.*?)"/g,"<span class='string-value'>&quot;$1&quot;</span>");
        data=data.replace(/&lt;\?(.*?)\s/g,"<span class='php-tag'>&lt;?$1</span>");
        data=data.replace(/\s\?&gt;/g,"<span class='php-tag'>?&gt;</span>");
        data=data.replace(/\/\* (.*?) \*\//g,"<span class='comment'>/* $1 */</span>");                   
        data=data.replace(/(new|echo|print|while|for|foreach|class|public|function|static|protected|private|return|required|required_once|include|include_once)[^=]/g,"<span class='reserved'> $1 </span>");
        data=data.replace(/\\n/g,"<br/>");
        data=data.replace(/\\t/g,"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp");
        obj[i].innerHTML=data;
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Code Highlighter</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/codeHighlighter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("load", codeHighlighter);
        </script>
        <style>
            code{
              font-family: arial;
            }
            .html-tag{
              color:#090;
            }
            .string-value{
              color:#900;
            }
            .reserved{
              color:#009;
            }
            .php-tag{
              color:#f00;
            }
            .comment{
              color:#444;
            }
        </style>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>This application highlights `php` and `html` code.</div>
        <code>
            /* A sample code. */\n
            &lt;div class="code" &gt;\n
            \t Hello!\n
            &lt;/div&gt;\n
            &lt;?php\n
            class Anish(){\n
            \n
            \t public function __construct(){\n
            \t\t return "Hello";\n
            \t }\n
            \n
            }\n
            $anish=new Anish();\n
            echo $anish;\n
            ?&gt;\n
        </code>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is yakk or antlr? can you give a url refrence to this?

Comment: Why don't you just use [PHP's built-in syntax highlighting function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-file.php)?

Comment: Looks like there are some parser generators for JavaScript. [PEG.js](http://pegjs.org/) being one of them. I'm sure a bit of searching would produce grammars for both PHP & HTML.

Comment: Also, check out [prism](http://prismjs.com/) if you want a client-side solution.

Answer (score 4):

Really accurate highlghting is a big challenge, and even if your implementation is not totally falsy it's very incomplete.

First some obvious points, easy to correct:

- your PHP reserved words list lacks a number of words, such as (not exhaustively) `global`, `const`,  `if`, `else`, `switch`, `case`, `default`, `do`, `exit`, `break`, `continue` `try`, `catch`, `finally`, ...
- you look for PHP multiline comments like `/*...*/` but not for simple line ones like `//...`, nor for HTML comments `<!--...-->`.
- you look for double-quoted strings `"..."` but not for single-quoted ones `'...'`.

Now some harder issues:

- you currently don't take care of escaped (single or double) quotes in a quoted string: `"quote \" inside quoted string"` breaks the highlighting.
- you don't look for numbers (integer or float)

Lastly, not a lack but might be improved: you don't distinct between HTML tags and their attributes.

**Please note** that this is not to criticize your work! At the opposite, since you said it is:

> to extend my knowledge in JS and regular expressions

I hope it encourages you to rise to the challenge :)

---

EDIT. Two points I forgot to mention above.

The first one comes from a preliminary general advice: try to follow best practices, notably in that, instead of:

```
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
```

you should write:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
```

and so on evrywhere...

So here is the point since when looking for reserved words you wrote this:

```
data = data.replace(/(new|echo|...|include|include_once)[^=]/g, ...
```

There you added `[^=]` to avoid selecting something like `$new=...`.
Right but regarding the above advice you must realize that one may have written `$new = ...` instead. Then you'll select `new` as a reserved word, while it's not!

So actually you'd better looking for a prepended `$` rather than an appended `=`:

```
data = data.replace(/[^\$(new|echo|...|include|include_once)/g, ...
```

The other point is only for convenience: currently you force `tab` to be arbitrarily replaced by 4 spaces, which may sometimes be undesired. So you might merely write something like this:

```
function codeHighlighter(tab) {
  tab = tab ? tab : 4;
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    ...
    data=data.replace(/\\t/g, repeat("&nbsp;", tab);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much! I'll try to overcome those problem....

Comment: @AnishSilwal Glad to help. BTW, I remembered I'd forgotten something important: look at my edit.